# How I can get or transfer data among different SCOs in SCORM 2004?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have an index SCO to list the index of different course modules(every module is a SCO), and I saved completion status(cmi.completion_status) in these module SCOs. Now I want to get these status in index SCO or transfer these values to cmi.suspend_data in Index SCO. How I can deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There was a concept of "Shared State Persistence" a bolt-on to SCORM 2004.  It is rarely supported.  Allows you to create a bucket of data that SCOs can reference for reading and writing data.  This occurs within the SSP namespace unlike CMI and ADL within the SCORM 2004 specification.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I worked with SCORM in detail, so I can't provide the details, but I believe you can achieve this using global objectives in SCORM 2004. I don't believe this is possible in SCORM 1.2.

Look at this [SCORM 2004 4th Edition Features](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_golf_examples?pmc=em-1) example.

Comment: With setting `adlcp:sharedDataGlobalToSystem="true"` and defining 
`<adlcp:data>
  <adlcp:map targetID="com.example.mydata" writeSharedData="true" />
</adlcp:data>`
you can persist data in between SCOs. In my tested LMS this data is even accessible between different courses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this client side at all - by definition every SCO is completely independent of every other SCO.

Saying that - it is possible to have rollups within the manifest - which can give some of the data to a parent SCO, unfortunately the [manifest structure](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/manifest-structure/) document doesn't explain how and I can't remember where it's documented.

The other way, which would work far better, is also more complicated to implement as you need code access to the server, and to manually pull all the data together to make it available for the index SCO - I'd also recommend using `cmi.launch_data` or something in the query string instead of `cmi.suspend_data` to separate it from anything you might want to save.

Hopefully someone else will come along and expand on the second possibility here - it's being done for something I'm working with, but I only have client access on that project.

Comment: If you're having to edit the server's implementation in order to get the client  package to work, then there's not a lot of point using an interoperability specification in the first place.

Comment: Depends what it's used for - in this case, thousands of activities for schoolchildren in a custom website - so SCORM is the starting point, and it's the global rewards that are linked to separate SCO trees that need the server changes. Sadly there's a limit to how much you can argue with the client - the best you can do is find the easiest and safest way to comply ;-)

Comment: Oh, and forgot to say - need to deal with the situation of the student being at different stages on different SCOs on different devices at the same time, but still give a correct total based on the number of 100% correct answers - and there is no way within the SCORM standard to support that ;-)

Comment: No, I recommend using a different interoperability specification for that use case e.g. Tin Can. (http://tincanapi.com)

Comment: Recommend whatever you'd like (we've already tried), but with an international company that has already invested millions in their platform, they're sticking with what they've paid for and putting more time and money into adding what they want to do, rather than changing platform to something better suited to it. Fortunately there are only two non-SCORM things on there, and only one actively makes for noncomformance... Hopefully someone else starting down this route will read and learn and save us devs a load of headaches by making the right decisions at the start :-P